# Call Google Map Geocode with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, phantomjs

I want to write a geocode function with phantomjs {input:address} -> {output:laglat}

However, after I include google api and write the following code it gives error and says: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google"

```
var page = new WebPage()
page.includeJs("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_KEY}&sensor=false", function() {
  var geocoder;
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = "507 W Florida Street, Chicago, Illinois"; // not real here
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
});
```

here is the error from the console:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google

geocode.js:4
:/modules/webpage.js:337
```

I am new to PhantomJS, could anybody give me a hint about how to revise my code? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The second argument for `includeJs` is the callback, after your script has been loaded.
But this callback still is in PhantomJS execution context, this is not your page's context.
You need to call `page.evaluate`. So, your code will be:

```
var page = new WebPage()
page.includeJs("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_KEY}&sensor=false", function() {
  // we're still in the main execution context
  page.evaluate(function() {
  // now we're in the context of a web page.
      var geocoder;
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var address = "507 W Florida Street, Chicago, Illinois"; // not real here
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
         } else {
             console.log("error");
         }
      });
   });
});
```